# How to get trainable weights for a manual run of session in Keras?

Tags: keras

Because I'm manually running a session, I can't seem to collect the trainable weights of a specific layer.

```
    x = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, init='he_normal', border_mode='same')(img)

    for i in range(0, self.blocks_per_group):
        nb_filters = 16 * self.widening_factor
        x = residual_block(x, nb_filters=nb_filters, subsample_factor=1)

    for i in range(0, self.blocks_per_group):
        nb_filters = 32 * self.widening_factor
        if i == 0:
            subsample_factor = 2
        else:
            subsample_factor = 1
        x = residual_block(x, nb_filters=nb_filters, subsample_factor=subsample_factor)

    for i in range(0, self.blocks_per_group):
        nb_filters = 64 * self.widening_factor
        if i == 0:
            subsample_factor = 2
        else:
            subsample_factor = 1
        x = residual_block(x, nb_filters=nb_filters, subsample_factor=subsample_factor)

    x = BatchNormalization(axis=3)(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8), strides=None, border_mode='valid')(x)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, np.prod(x.get_shape()[1:].as_list())])

    # Readout layer
    preds = Dense(self.nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

   loss = tf.reduce_mean(categorical_crossentropy(labels, preds))

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

    with sess.as_default():

        for i in range(10):

            batch = self.next_batch(self.batch_num)
            _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss],
                            feed_dict={img: batch[0], labels: batch[1]})
            print(l)
            print(type(weights))
```

I'm trying to get the weights of the last convolution layer.

I tried `get_trainable_weights(layer)` and `layer.get_weights()`but I did not manage to get anywhere.

The error

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'trainable_weights'
```

Answer (score -1):

From looking at the source* it seems like your looking for layer.trainable_weights (it's a list not a member function). Please note this returns tensors.

If you want to get their actual values, you need to evaluate them in a session:

```
weights1, weights2 = sess.run([weight_tensor_1, weight_tensor_2])
```

*https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L401